# How to get Requesting Party Token (RPT) by API in Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, keycloak-rest-api

I am to struggling to find it but I can't find a solution. Does anyone help me?

Here is my try.
#1 First find PAT (Protection API Token)
[image]

#2 get the permission ticket list
[image]

#3 try get RPT but got "Ticket verification failed" error.
[image]

#4 This source code for this error but I am not familiar with the source.

```
    private PermissionTicketToken verifyPermissionTicket(KeycloakAuthorizationRequest request) {
        String ticketString = request.getTicket();

        PermissionTicketToken ticket = request.getKeycloakSession().tokens().decode(ticketString, PermissionTicketToken.class);
        if (ticket == null) {
            throw new CorsErrorResponseException(request.getCors(), "invalid_ticket", "Ticket verification failed", Status.FORBIDDEN);
        }
```

It copy from source file(AuthorizationTokenService.java) on line 670.
[image]

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_overview

Answer (score 5):

I spent a lot of time trying to get the RPT and i finally found a solution.

So first you have to get a normal token with the grant_type password :

[image]

Then you ask for the party token with the access_token you received, this time your grant_type will be *"urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket"*

[image]

NOTE: here the audience property is the client_id

Comment: Hello, would it be possible the paste the entire request here. It is very confusing for me and I cannot get it working :(

Comment: Hi @avimehenwal,  what do you mean about the entire request? The screenshots I posted are the requests

Answer (score 1):

That's quite an advanced / emerging standard you are looking at. User Managed Access is related to User A granting resource access to other users based on verifiable preconditions.

Is that really what you are trying to do? If you can explain your scenario / requirements - eg what components there are - we may be able to suggest a simpler / alternative solution .

Comment: I want to makes a resource server and authorization server on Keycloak. The resource server means provides a custom resource HTTP get/post methods by REST API call. examples for getting a book list. booklist is one of the resources. I found Keycloak support UMA(User Management Access) 2 compliance API.  It's token called Protection API Token(PAT). This is documentation. https://docs.kantarainitiative.org/uma/wg/rec-oauth-uma-grant-2.0.html  Scenario set the resource server -> get permission ticket -> get RPT -> call API -> get resource.

Comment: I'm wondering if that's the right flow for you though, or if the Keycloak documentation is confusing things? The most standard option is for a client (eg a UI) to authenticate + get an access token, send it to the API, then the API verifies the token. See steps 4, 8, 15 and 16 of my [Messages Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/). Would that work for you if you could do it in Keycloak?

Comment: Yep, Keycloak documentation is confusing not a crystal clear. Your post is OAuth flow not UMA flow. UMA 2 is a ‘party-to-party’ authorization protocol based on the OAuth2 authorization framework.  grant_type is  "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket" This is clean documentation example. https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/am/6/uma-guide/

Comment: Ok cool - so you need the more advanced options then, since you have specific requirements around external party resource access after a user has consented. I've read about UMA but have not implemented it - very few authorization servers support it. My comments were just in case you were heading down a wrong technical path. Good luck - your best options are the Keycloak resources I think.